# PyInstaller not finding Excel files in bundled executable

Tags: python, excel, path, pyinstaller, executable

I am facing an issue with PyInstaller while trying to bundle my Python script into an executable. The script relies on Excel files located in a directory called "Stations_list". However, when running the generated executable, it fails to find the Excel files and throws a "File Not Found" error.

**This is the part of my code where I use the excel files:**

```
def save_data():
    # Create a folder to save the files in
    dossier_dir = "Dossier"
    if not os.path.exists(dossier_dir):
        os.makedirs(dossier_dir)

    # Set the base_path environment variable to the directory containing the script
    os.environ['base_path'] = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

    files_to_process = glob.glob( str(pathlib.Path(os.environ.get('base_path')) / 'Stations_list/*.xlsx') )

    # Check if any Excel file exists in the Stations_list directory
    if len(files_to_process) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("File Not Found", "No Excel files found in the 'Stations_list' directory.")
        return []

    result = []
    # Retrieve the Excel files from the list
    for excel_file in files_to_process:                
        # Read the data frame with the stations
        data_frame = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        
        # Iterate over the IP addresses and check their status
        for index, row in data_frame.iterrows():
            i = 1
            while True:
                try:
                    if check_ip(row["IP"]):
                        break
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        if i < 6:
                            # Append data to the result list
                            result.append([
                                row["IP"],
                                row["Type de station"],
                                row["Wilaya"],
                                row["Commune"],
                                row["ID"]
                            ])
                            break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Error")
        
    return result
```

I have tried multiple approaches mentioned on Stack Overflow, including setting the base path and using glob to retrieve the file paths dynamically. I even attempted to create a spec file with the necessary paths explicitly added. Unfortunately, none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

**Spec file:**

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PyInstaller import __version__

# Set the path to the script file
script_path = Path('final_version.py')

# Set the path to the directory containing the script
base_path = script_path.parent

# Set the path to the Stations_list directory
stations_dir = base_path / 'Stations_list'

# Add the paths to include them in the bundled executable
sys.path.append(str(base_path))
sys.path.append(str(stations_dir))

a = Analysis(
    [str(script_path)],
    pathex=[str(base_path)],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[(str(stations_dir), 'Stations_list')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=None if __version__.startswith('3.6') else [],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    noarchive=False,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='script',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
)
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem and ensure that the bundled executable can access the required Excel files. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the files because you are doing it wrong, you are not joining file paths, you are trying to join strings with file path joining operator, that won't work.

I am sure if you try to run your code you will encounter this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

It is caused by this:

```
str(pathlib.Path(os.environ.get('base_path')) / 'Stations_list/*.xlsx')
```

Path extension operator can only work with `Path` objects, and not `str`.

remove that `str` cast and it will work.

But then you are doing unnecessary things, why set `os.environ['base_path'] = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` and then immediately use `os.environ.get('base_path')` to get the input? It is slow and stupid, but more importantly it prevents your code from ever working, because you need the full path, but you only get the directory name, you can't work with relative path here.

But then you are using too many libraries together here, the aren't compatible with each other at all, and you haven't mastered any of them, it is really a bad practice.

Don't use `glob`, use `Path.rglob`

First, add the following line at the top of your script:

```
from pathlib import Path
```

Then, replace the following two lines:

```
os.environ['base_path'] = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

files_to_process = glob.glob( str(pathlib.Path(os.environ.get('base_path')) / 'Stations_list/*.xlsx') )

With:

```
files_to_process = (Path(sys.argv[0]) / 'Stations_list/').rglob('*.xlsx')
```

It should work.

---

### **Edit**

Your modification is still essentially the same as mine. `Path.parent` is still a `Path` object.

You never specified your input, it is no fault of mine.

You are doing extra steps again.

If you pass it 'C:\foo\blah' but you need 'C:\foo' for it to work, just pasd 'C:\foo' directly.

And in Python, use `'C:\\foo'` or `'C:/foo'` or `r'C:\foo'`

Comment: It doesn't work. I had to modify your code for it to work, but it doesn't as an exe file. 
    files_to_process = (Path(sys.argv[0]).parent / 'Stations_list/').rglob('*.xlsx')